# Error running MBUnit test from Visual Studio using TestDriven.Net

Tags: testdriven.net

I'm getting the following error trying to execute a unit test from Visual Studio.  I've poked around a little, and have re-installed both Gallio and TD.Net, but still get the same error.  I'm kind of clueless on where to begin, and searching google turns up next to nothing...

```
Gallio.Loader.LoaderException: Gallio.Loader.LoaderException: Failed to setup the runtime. ---> Gallio.Runtime.RuntimeException: The runtime could not be initialized. ---> Gallio.Runtime.RuntimeException: Could not register component 'TDNetRunner.UI.PlaceholderPreferencePaneProvider' of plugin 'Gallio.TDNetRunner.UI' because it implements service 'Gallio.UI.PreferencePaneProvider' which was not found in the registry.
```

at Gallio.Runtime.Extensibility.PluginCatalog.RegisterComponents(IRegistry registry, IList`1 topologicallySortedPlugins, IList`1 pluginDescriptors) in c:\Server\Projects\MbUnit v3.3\Work\src\Gallio\Gallio\Runtime\Extensibility\PluginCatalog.cs:line 225
   at Gallio.Runtime.Extensibility.PluginCatalog.ApplyTo(IRegistry registry) in c:\Server\Projects\MbUnit v3.3\Work\src\Gallio\Gallio\Runtime\Extensibility\PluginCatalog.cs:line 69
   at Gallio.Runtime.DefaultRuntime.RegisterLoadedPlugins() in c:\Server\Projects\MbUnit v3.3\Work\src\Gallio\Gallio\Runtime\DefaultRuntime.cs:line 270
   at Gallio.Runtime.DefaultRuntime.Initialize() in c:\Server\Projects\MbUnit v3.3\Work\src\Gallio\Gallio\Runtime\DefaultRuntime.cs:line 170
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Gallio.Runtime.DefaultRuntime.Initialize() in c:\Server\Projects\MbUnit v3.3\Work\src\Gallio\Gallio\Runtime\DefaultRuntime.cs:line 197
   at Gallio.Runtime.RuntimeBootstrap.Initialize(RuntimeSetup setup, ILogger logger) in c:\Server\Projects\MbUnit v3.3\Work\src\Gallio\Gallio\Runtime\RuntimeBootstrap.cs:line 74
   at Gallio.Runtime.Loader.GallioLoaderBootstrap.SetupRuntime(String runtimePath) in c:\Server\Projects\MbUnit v3.3\Work\src\Gallio\Gallio\Runtime\Loader\GallioLoaderBootstrap.cs:line 49
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Gallio.Loader.LoaderManager.LoaderImpl.SetupRuntime()
   at Gallio.Loader.Isolation.IsolatedEnvironmentManager.IsolatedInitializer.SetupRuntime()
   at Gallio.Loader.Isolation.IsolatedEnvironmentManager.IsolatedEnvironment.UnwrapException(Exception ex)
   at Gallio.Loader.Isolation.IsolatedEnvironmentManager.IsolatedEnvironment.SetupRuntime()
   at Gallio.Loader.SharedEnvironment.SharedEnvironmentManager.CreateSharedEnvironment()
   at Gallio.Loader.SharedEnvironment.SharedEnvironmentManager.GetSharedEnvironment()
   at Gallio.TDNetRunner.Core.LocalProxyTestRunner.CreateRemoteProxyTestRunner()
   at Gallio.TDNetRunner.Core.LocalProxyTestRunner.RunImpl(IFacadeTestListener testListener, String assemblyPath, String cref, FacadeOptions facadeOptions)
   at Gallio.TDNetRunner.Core.BaseProxyTestRunner.Run(IFacadeTestListener testListener, String assemblyPath, String cref, FacadeOptions facadeOptions)
    System.Runtime.Remoting.ServerException: Gallio.Loader.LoaderException: Gallio.Loader.LoaderException: Failed to setup the runtime. ---> Gallio.Runtime.RuntimeException: The runtime could not be initialized. ---> Gallio.Runtime.RuntimeException: Could not register component 'TDNetRunner.UI.PlaceholderPreferencePaneProvider' of plugin 'Gallio.TDNetRunner.UI' because it implements service 'Gallio.UI.PreferencePaneProvider' which was not found in the registry.
    at Gallio.Runtime.Extensibility.PluginCatalog.RegisterComponents(IRegistry registry, IList`1 topologicallySortedPlugins, IList`1 pluginDescriptors)
    at Gallio.Runtime.Extensibility.PluginCatalog.ApplyTo(IRegistry registry)
    at Gallio.Runtime.DefaultRuntime.RegisterLoadedPlugins()
    at Gallio.Runtime.DefaultRuntime.Initialize()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Gallio.Runtime.DefaultRuntime.Initialize()
    at Gallio.Runtime.RuntimeBootstrap.Initialize(RuntimeSetup setup, ILogger logger)
    at Gallio.Runtime.Loader.GallioLoaderBootstrap.SetupRuntime(String runtimePath)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Gallio.Loader.LoaderManager.LoaderImpl.SetupRuntime()
    at Gallio.Loader.Isolation.IsolatedEnvironmentManager.IsolatedInitializer.SetupRuntime()
    at Gallio.Loader.Isolation.IsolatedEnvironmentManager.IsolatedEnvironment.UnwrapException(Exception ex)
    at Gallio.Loader.Isolation.IsolatedEnvironmentManager.IsolatedEnvironment.SetupRuntime()
    at Gallio.Loader.SharedEnvironment.SharedEnvironmentManager.CreateSharedEnvironment()
    at Gallio.Loader.SharedEnvironment.SharedEnvironmentManager.GetSharedEnvironment()
    at Gallio.TDNetRunner.Core.LocalProxyTestRunner.CreateRemoteProxyTestRunner()
    at Gallio.TDNetRunner.Core.LocalProxyTestRunner.RunImpl(IFacadeTestListener testListener, String assemblyPath, String cref, FacadeOptions facadeOptions)
    at Gallio.TDNetRunner.Core.BaseProxyTestRunner.Run(IFacadeTestListener testListener, String assemblyPath, String cref, FacadeOptions facadeOptions)
    at Gallio.TDNetRunner.Core.BaseProxyTestRunner.Run(IFacadeTestListener testListener, String assemblyPath, String cref, FacadeOptions facadeOptions)
    at Gallio.TDNetRunner.GallioResidentTestRunner.Run(ITestListener testListener, String assemblyFile, String cref)
    at TestDriven.TestRunner.AdaptorTestRunner.Run(ITestListener testListener, ITraceListener traceListener, String assemblyPath, String testPath)
    at TestDriven.TestRunner.ThreadTestRunner.Runner.Run()

0 passed, 1 failed, 0 skipped, took 4.01 seconds (MbUnit v3.3).

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a similar issue running Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8 (32-bit) with JetBrains ReSharper 7.1.10000.900, GallioBundle 3.4.14.0 and TestDriven.NET 3.4.2808 installed, assuming you are running a setup similar to the above mine, I was able to resolve this situation by doing the following:

1. Shutdown all copies of Visual Studio
2. Uninstall ReSharper and TD.Net
3. First re-install Gallio and ReSharper
4. Install the latest TestDriven (in my case 3.4.2808 Personal)
5. Start Visual Studio and right click to run tests.